# Why is my System.Linq.Expressions code-gen slow at runtime and how can I make it faster?

Tags: c#, performance, generics, lambda, code-generation

I am trying to implement a function that returns functions that calculate the vectors' scalar product. It should be implemented via generics, but it seems possible only by generating code in the run time. Read several docs about code generation by building expression trees and this is what I have written so far:

```
public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    ParameterExpression first  = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "first" );
    ParameterExpression second = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T[]), "second");
    ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)  , "result");
    ParameterExpression index  = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "index" );

    LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(T));

    BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
        new[] { result, index },
        Expression.Assign( result, Expression.Constant(0) ),
        Expression.Assign( index , Expression.Constant(0) ),

        Expression.Loop(
            Expression.IfThenElse(
                Expression.LessThan( index, Expression.ArrayLength( first ) ),
                Expression.Block(
                    Expression.AddAssign( result, Expression.Multiply( Expression.ArrayIndex( first, index ), Expression.ArrayIndex( second, index ) ) ),
                    Expression.Increment( index )
                ),
                Expression.Break( label, result )
            ),
            label
        )
    );

    return Expression
        .Lambda<Func<T[], T[], T>>( block, first, second )
        .Compile();
}
```

This builds without problem but takes forever to run tests. I have a hard time wrapping my head around the subject. So I don't know what exactly went wrong.

This is a piece of tests that this method is used:

```
[Test]
public void GetVectorMultiplyFunctionReturnsFunctionForLong()
{
    var first = new long[] { 1L, 2L, 3L };
    var second = new long[] { 2L, 2L, 2L };
    var expected = 1L * 2L + 2L * 2L + 3L * 2L;
    var func = CodeGeneration.GetVectorMultiplyFunction<long>();
    var actual = func(first, second);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? What are the **actual** types you expect `T` to be? ...because IME `T` will only ever be `Double`, `Single` (`float`), maybe `Int32` and/or `Int64`, or maybe `BigInteger` if you're brave - given that's only 3 or 4 different types it doesn't make sense to use generics, just copy+paste.

Comment: Also, assuming you _actually do_ need to generate methods at runtime, have you considered using Reflection.Emit instead of faffing around with `System.Linq.Expressions`?

Comment: Finally, you haven't shown us where or how you're using `GetVectorMultiplyFunction` - nor have you explained how any benchmarking or profiling you've done (and you have done them, right?) indicates that this method is the bottleneck or hotspot.

Comment: I did it according to the task specification. Remember this is for learning purposes only and is not used anywhere beyond that.

Comment: And yes, it is my bad that I didn't provide a piece from tests. I think I should make an edit

Comment: There may not be anything that is wrong.  You need to do testing to understand better why code is taking longer to run.  I disagree with Dai that Linq is the source of issue.  Usually Linq take that same amount of time to run as other methods.  Parsing Expression Tree "properly" can take lots of time and using other methods may look like a better solution but may not correctly get proper results.

Comment: @jdweng I did not attribute any problems to the use of Linq.Expressions - my point was that using Reflection.Emit directly is a viable alternative to Linq.Expressions for codegen and that the OP should consider trying it if they continue to hit roadblocks.

Comment: @Dai : Just curious.  Is there data indicating Reflection.Emit is more efficient than Linq.Expression?

Comment: @jdweng It’s not “more efficient” - it’s just a lower-level API. Linq.Expressions (when used with Linq-to-Objects) uses Emit internally.  I feel the main advantage of using Emit is the sheer control it gives you: it’s great for doing things that are impossible in C# whereas Linq.Expressions is far more limited in what you can do with it.

Comment: @Dai : The code is working.  This is a speed issue.  Does it make sense to modify working code in this case?

Comment: @jdweng I’m investigating the performance of the OP’s code right now. I’ll report back soon.

Comment: @jdweng Also, something like vector-multiplication is better done with Emit because you can use intrinsics like AVX and SSE which are perfect for number-crunching ops.

Comment: @Dai : The OP may not need better precision, just faster runtime.  Stay focus on the root problem and do not try to fix something that doesn't need changes.  I do not know all the libraries that are being used.  This may be a memory issue when large amount of memory is being used and runtime is slow due to swap space being used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some debugging in Linqpad, the problem isn't that your dynamic method is "slow" (it isn't), the problem is that the method contains an infinite-loop that never exits.

---

From what I can tell, your `GetVectorMultiplyFunction` method is *meant* to do something like this, if it were written in C# directly:

```cs
static T[] VectorMultiply<T>( T[] first, T[] second )
    where T : struct
{
    T     result = default(T);
    Int32 index  = 0;
    
    while( true )
    {
        if( index < first.Length )
        {
            result += first[index] * second[index];
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

...however there's a few major bugs in your code:

- ```
  ParameterExpression result = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T)  , "result");
  ParameterExpression index  = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "index" );
  ```

  - These two lines should use `Expression.Variable`, not `Expression.Parameter` as `result` and `index` are not method parameters, but method locals.
- ```
  Expression.Assign( result, Expression.Constant(0) )
  ```

  - This doesn't work because `result` is typed as `T`, but `Expression.Constant(0)` is typed as `Int32` (because the `0` literal is an `Int32` literal.
  - Change it to use `default(T)`, like so:

    ```
    Expression.Assign( result, Expression.Constant( default(T) ) ),
    ```
- ```
  LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(T));
  ```

  - Change the above to this:

    ```
    LabelTarget breakLabel = Expression.Label("break");
    ```
- **Here's the main bug** and the cause of the infinite-loop:

  ```
  Expression.Increment( index )
  ```

  The above does increment `index`, but it doesn't reassign the incremented value back to the `index` local, so it's the same thing as doing this in C#:

  ```
  while( true ) {
      if( index < first.Length )
      {
          result += first[index]  * second[index];
          index + 1;       // <-- *DANGER, WILL ROBINSON!*
      }
      else
      {
          break;
      }
  }
  ```

  - See the problem? Doing `index + 1` never actually increases `index`, so `index < first.Length` is **always true** so the `while` loop never stops.
  - The fix is to change it to `index += 1` (or `++index` or `index++`) like so:

    ```
    Expression.PostIncrementAssign( index )
    ```
- The last issue is that your outermost `Expression.Block`'s last expression should be the `result` local, which is equivalent to doing `return result;` in C#.

  - So *immediately after* the `Expression.Loop()` call inside your `Expression.Block( variables, expressions )` call-site, just add `result` as another parameter.
  - I'll confess that I still don't yet fully understand how the `breakLabel = Expression.Label("break");` expression works or what it even does, but [it works for me](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/)...
- I've also added calls to `Console.WriteLine(String, Object)` as a quick substitute for the lack of step-through debugger support in dynamic-methods - that's how I noticed that `index` was always `0`.

  - [Screenshot proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUyhn.png): 
    [image]

---

This code works for me in .NET 6:

```cs
public static Func<T[], T[], T> GetVectorMultiplyFunction<T>()
    where T : struct
{
    var writeLineMethod = typeof(Console).GetMethod( nameof(Console.WriteLine), new[] { typeof(String), typeof(Object) })!; // print-style debugging ugh // `public static void WriteLine(string format, object? arg0)`
    
    ParameterExpression first  = Expression.Parameter( type: typeof(T[])  , name: "first"  );
    ParameterExpression second = Expression.Parameter( type: typeof(T[])  , name: "second" );
    ParameterExpression result = Expression.Variable ( type: typeof(T)    , name: "result" );
    ParameterExpression index  = Expression.Variable ( type: typeof(Int32), name: "index"  );
    
    LabelTarget breakLabel = Expression.Label("break");
    
    BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(
        variables  : new[] { result, index },
        expressions: new Expression[]
        {
            Expression.Assign( result, Expression.Constant( default(T) ) ),
            Expression.Assign( index , Expression.Constant(          0 ) ),
            
            Expression.Loop(
                body: Expression.Block(
                    Expression.IfThenElse(
                        test  : Expression.LessThan( index, Expression.ArrayLength( first ) ),
                        ifTrue: Expression.Block(
                            Expression.AddAssign( result, Expression.Multiply( Expression.ArrayIndex( first, index ), Expression.ArrayIndex( second, index) ) ),
                            Expression.PostIncrementAssign( index ),
                            
                            Expression.Call( writeLineMethod, Expression.Constant( "result: {0}" ), Expression.Convert( result, typeof(Object) ) ),
                            Expression.Call( writeLineMethod, Expression.Constant( "index : {0}" ), Expression.Convert( index , typeof(Object) ) )
                        ),
                        ifFalse: Expression.Break( breakLabel )
                    )
                ),
                @break: breakLabel
            ),
            result
        }
    );
    
    Func<T[],T[],T> f = Expression
        .Lambda< Func<T[],T[],T> >( block, first, second )
        .Compile();
    
    return f;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the `func` returning the correct expected result, as well as the `Console.WriteLine` output with the logged values of `result` and `index`. The method runs *instantly* (and the `Expression.Lambda<>(...).Compile()` call only took 0.5ms on my machine too):

[image]